# Parameter to script tool gives Invalid expression ERROR 000358?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, error-000358

I have created python script tool in arcgis 10.1 as below.
I am trying to take input parameter and passing to select statement.

There is error when i execute this tool.

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "Database Connections\sc_dev.sde"

name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("SC.STATES", "NEW_SELECTION", " \"STATE_NAME\" = name")
```

The error is Failed to execute....Invalid expression..ERROR 000358

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that name is set to a string and that STATE_NAME is a text field.

In which case I think this should work.

Change:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("SC.STATES", "NEW_SELECTION", " \"STATE_NAME\" = name")
```

to:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("SC.STATES", "NEW_SELECTION", '"STATE_NAME" = ' + "'" + name + "'")
```

Note how I:

- enclose `"STATE_NAME" =` inside single quotes (because the field name is delimited by double quotes);
- enable the `name` variable to be evaluated by not having quotes around it
- need to place single quotes around the *value* of `name`, which I do by enclosing each of them in double quotes.

---

The below syntax will also work, and is the way that I would normally do it nowadays:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("SC.STATES", "NEW_SELECTION", "STATE_NAME = '{0}'".format(name))
```

The above uses Python formatting syntax to construct the where_clause.